# Can I generate two PWM with 90°phase shift from stm8 microcontroller?

Tags: pwm, stm8

I am using stm8 microcontroller(STM8AF288) to generate a PWM of 1KHz frequency with timer-1(16bit) . I am giving this as input to a circuit， which generates two PWMs with 90° phase shift. But unfortunately that circuit got damaged. It's no more working. So I thought to generate  2 PWMs with 90° phase shift.

Is it possible to do so? In stm8 user manual I couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: You need to include the micocontroller part number if you want this answered in a serious way.

Comment: How are you generating the value for the PWM?

Comment: Depends on the PWM frequency and the desired PWM resolution.  Please add that information to your question.

Comment: According to one of their application notes... yes.. http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/44/2c/2c/ee/cb/ea/4e/1d/CD00270970.pdf/files/CD00270970.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00270970.pdf

Comment: > Is it possible to do so? certainly - just rebuild your damaged circuit and you are in.